# Tidyverse mutation difficulties with factors

Tags: r, date, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df <- tibble(YrMo = as.factor(str_sub(ymd(c("2014-01-19", "2014-02-14")),1,7)))
df
#>  YrMo   
#>  <fct>  
#>  1 2014-01
#>  2 2014-02
```

I'm trying to create a second column `YrMo2` utilizing some tidyverse functions. The two expected outputs are `2014-Jan` and `2014-Feb` but I instead get `NA`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    YrMo2 = 
      factor(YrMo, 
             levels = format(as.Date(paste0(levels(YrMo), "-01")), "%Y-%b")
             )
    )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   YrMo      YrMo2
#>   <fct>     <fct>
#>   1 2014-01 NA   
#>   2 2014-02 NA
```

I "know" this should work because the base-R function works:

```
format(as.Date(paste0(levels(df$YrMo), "-01")), "%Y-%b")
#> [1] "2014-Jan" "2014-Feb"
```

Seems evident my syntax is off. But where? Or maybe it's my logic.

Comment: When using `factor()` to create a new factor, the `levels=` need to actually match the values in the vector. if they don't match, they are coded as NA. If you want the different names, use `labels=` in an order that match the corresponding `levels=`.

Comment: I recommend against the overly-broad use of `library(tidyverse)`. It is a handy meta-package that can be used to ensure all of its dependency packages are installed, but loading everything when you only need (in this example) three packages is a bit heavy-handed. In this case, I'd reduce it to `dplyr` in place of `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    YrMo2 = factor(
      format(as.Date(paste0(YrMo, "-01")), "%Y-%b"), 
      levels = format(as.Date(paste0(levels(YrMo), "-01")), "%Y-%b")
    )
  )
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  YrMo    YrMo2   
#  <fct>   <fct>   
#1 2014-01 2014-Jan
#2 2014-02 2014-Feb
```

Your issue was that you were changing the `levels` argument to `factor` to levels which did not exist in the first argument passed, which will return `NA`:

```
factor("X", levels = "x")
#[1] <NA>
#Levels: x
```

Comment: and how would I specify the levels to be in chronological order? In base-R it would be in the following vein: `x <- as.factor(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03")); levels(x) <- format(as.Date(paste0(levels(x), "-01")), "%Y-%b"); levels(x)`  Do you mind including it in your answer?

Comment: See my edit, this should preserve the order of the levels in `YrMo2`.

Answer (score 2):

The `forcats` package has helper functons to make it easier to work with levels
If you started with a string, then you could do

```
library(forcats)
df <- tibble(YrMo = str_sub(ymd(c("2014-01-19", "2014-02-14")),1,7))
df %>% mutate(
  YrMo2 = fct_relabel(factor(YrMo, levels=sort(YrMo)), ~format(as.Date(paste0(.x, "-01")), "%Y-%b"))
)
```

We use `factor(YrMo, levels=sort(YrMo))` to make sure the values are sorted properly, then we use `fct_relabel()` to reformat the levels while preserving the order.